# Bootstrap icons with background colour

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-icons

I'm using bootstrap icons (the webfont, not the svg).

I want to apply a background to the icon, contained within its edges. But the colour is applied to the entire element.

For example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<div class="p-3" style="font-size:3rem">
  <i class="bi bi-emoji-smile bg-warning"></i>
  <i class="bi bi-heart bg-danger"></i>
  <i class="bi bi-circle bg-success"></i>
  <i class="bi bi-bluetooth bg-primary"></i>
<div>
```

I do not want to use the svg option.

Answer (score 2):

Please try below code:

```html
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

    <div class="p-3" style="font-size:3rem">
    <i class="bi bi-emoji-smile-fill text-warning"></i>
      <i class="bi bi-heart-fill text-danger"></i>
      <i class="bi bi-circle-fill text-primary"></i>
    <div>
```

This will fill in the background of the edge.
Please let me know if you find any issue with the code.

Comment: Thanks Kairav! But luckily, those three icons have a "filled" variant. What about an icon that does not? For example, check my update to the question - it shows a "bluetooth" icon which does not have a filled variant...

Comment: I find almost all the icons are come along with fill variant and in bootstrap there are 684 fill icons.

Comment: bluetooth is already come along with fill variant flow only

Comment: Very true, but a generic solution is required for those cases which lack a fill icon (e.g. bletooth). I was thinking maybe some kind of clipping path but I'm unsure how to do that.